# How to generate an image with a number in it?

Tags: bash, imagemagick

This command from ImageMagic creates an image writing the value of variable `var` in its center:

```
convert -size 512x512 xc:none -font "Free-Monospaced-Bold" -pointsize 180 -gravity center -draw 'text 0,0 '"$var"' ' "$var".png
```

While it works well for strings, it fails when the value of `var` is a number:

```
convert-im6.q16: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `text' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3265.
```

Since variables in bash are untyped, there's no way to transform it into a string (command `printf` will leave it as it is, a number), so the point must be to change the `text` argument in the command.

How to generate the image when the variable is numeric (positive, negative and real numbers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [the documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#draw) for `-draw`'s `text` operator only says that the string to render needs to be quoted if it has spaces, it appears it also needs to be quoted if it's numeric. So...

```
-draw "text 0,0 '$var' "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also put a number in an image in Imagemagick using -annotate in place of -draw.

```
var=7
convert -size 512x512 xc:none -font "Free-Monospaced-Bold" -pointsize 180 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 "$var" "$var".png

Or

var=7
convert -size 512x512 xc:none -font "Free-Monospaced-Bold" -pointsize 180 -gravity center -annotate +0+0 $var $var.png
```

But safest to use double quotes